# iFrame.src truncating get variables?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have the following code to set the src of an iFrame

```
    alert(this.options.url);
    this.iframe.src = url || this.options.url;
```

The alert reads

```
user_messages_new.php?to_user=bob marley&to_id=abatu&
```

The source produced (firebug) reads

```
src="javascript:false;"
```

And the iFrame loads

```
user_messages_new.php
```

What the hell is going on?

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but if you replace your alert with alert(url); what do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to change `this.iframe.src = url || this.options.url;` to `this.iframe.src = this.options.url;` If "url" were null, your code would work as is, but since it's false, it isn't working.